# Increment text and auto chmod script

Tags: php, optimization, increment, chmod

I have a script block wich count founded and edited files

```
foreach ($files as $file)
    {
    $info['founded']++;

        $Checkfile = file_get_contents($file);
        if(!strpos($Checkfile, $searchfor))
        { //If string NOT exists in the file
            $p_chmod=substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4); //Get file perm value
            if (!is_writable($file))
            { //if is NOT writable
                if(chmod($file,0777)) //Try to set perm
                { //If perm sett
                $t_mod=@filemtime($file);
                $str=file_get_contents($file);
                $sub_count= substr_count($str,$place);
                    if ($sub_count>0)
                    {
                    $info['replaces'] += $sub_count;
                    $info['edited_files']++;
                    $str=str_replace($place,$frame,$str);
                    file_put_contents($file,$str);
                    @touch($file,$t_mod,$t_mod); 
                    @chmod($file,$p_chmod);
                    }
                    } //If perm NOT sett
                    else  $info['nowritable']++;
                }
            } //if file is writable
            else
            {
                $t_mod=@filemtime($file);
                $str=file_get_contents($file);
                $sub_count= substr_count($str,$place);
                    if ($sub_count>0)
                    {
                    $info['replaces'] += $sub_count;
                    $info['edited_files']++;
                    $str=str_replace($place,$frame,$str);
                    file_put_contents($file,$str);
                    @touch($file,$t_mod,$t_mod);
                    @chmod($file,$p_chmod);
                    }
            }
        }
        else //If string exists in the file
        {
            $info['exist_files']++;
        }
    return $info;
    }
```

and how to echo founded files, something like

```
$info['foundedFiles']= text & \n & text;
echo $info['foundedFiles']
```

and what to do if founded files would be about 10000? the takes a lot of page source? maybe echo in scroll box, but how to do that without writing to disk?

How to optimize this code?

Answer (score 1):

chmod is executed as follows:

chmod(DIR, MODE);

chmod("/directory/file.html", 0777);

It will take a decent amount of time on the client side of the program, and might even time out if there are enough files. It will take a decent amount of resources.